# LilyPond - Can I programmatically make Lyrics align after line breaks?

Tags: lilypond

Let’s say I’ve got two lines of music and words, represented here by bullets:

```
  \lyricmode {
    doe ray songs i whooosh
    there’s two lines you say
  }
```

```
   •   •    •   •    •
  doe ray songs i whooosh

   •     •    •    •   •
there’s two lines you say
```

As far as I can tell (and as illustrated above), LilyPond automatically aligns the center of `LyricText` with the center of `NoteHead`. (Or something close to that.)

##### The Question:

**Without having to know where line breaks occur**, is there a way to automatically apply a change to the first syllable of the line? The change in this case is alignment, but I would be curious if it can be adapted for other changes.

##### What I Don’t Want:

Explicitly overriding the alignment with `\once \override LyricText.self-alignment-X = #LEFT`:

```
  left_here = \once \override LyricText.self-alignment-X = #LEFT
  \lyricmode {
    \left_here doe ray songs i whooosh
    \left_here there’s two lines you say
  }
```

```
   •    •    •   •    •              
   doe ray songs i whooosh     ┌─────────────────────┐
                               │ THIS WORKS FINE ... │
   •        •    •    •   •    └─────────────────────┘
   there’s two lines you say

-----

   •    •    •   
   doe ray songs             ┌───────────────────────┐
                             │ ... UNTIL THE LINE    │
   •    •    •               │ BREAKS ARE DIFFERENT. │
   i whooosh there’s         └───────────────────────┘

   •    •    •   •
  two lines you say
```

##### What I Do Want:

```
  ┌─────────────────────────┐
  │  INSERT PROBABLY SOME   │
  │ MAGICAL SCHEME FUNCTION │
  └─────────────────────────┘
  \lyricmode {
    doe ray songs i whooosh
    there’s two lines you say
  }
```

```
   •    •    •   •    •       ┌─────────────────────────┐
   doe ray songs i whooosh    │ LEFT-ALIGNED LYRICS,    │
                              │ AUTOMATICALLY APPLIED   │
   •        •    •    •   •   │ AT THE BEGINNING OF THE │
   there’s two lines you say  │ LINE!                   │
                              └─────────────────────────┘
-----

   •    •    •   
   doe ray songs             ┌───────┐
                             │ SAME! │
   •    •       •            └───────┘
   i whooosh there’s         

   •     •    •   •
   two lines you say
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something this would work:

```
#(define (shift-first-syllable grob)
   (if (end-broken-spanner? grob)
       (begin
        (ly:grob-translate-axis!
         (ly:spanner-bound grob RIGHT)
         (- (ly:grob-property (ly:spanner-bound grob RIGHT) 'X-offset))
         X))))

{
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  \repeat unfold 64 c'8
} \addlyrics {
  \override LyricSpace.after-line-breaking = #shift-first-syllable 
  \override LyricHyphen.after-line-breaking = #shift-first-syllable 
  \override LyricExtender.after-line-breaking = #shift-first-syllable 
  
  aaaaa bbbbb \break ccccc ddddd -- \break eeeee -- fffff __ \break _
  \repeat unfold 64 xxx --
}
```

This might cause collisions with tight spacing. Generally Lilypond requires to work out Lyrics spacing to be able to determine line breaking in the first place.